# How to limit DropBox Camera Upload to only Camera images?

Tags: photos, dropbox

I've used Dropbox and its Camera Upload feature for a while now, both on my old phone (SE R800 I believe), and my newer Samsung S4 Mini.

It used to be that only pictures taken with the camera were uploaded by Camera Upload. I'm not sure if it was on the old phone or on an older version of Dropbox.

Nowadays, it seems like every single image file on the S4 is being uploaded. I haven't verified that it actually uploads everything, but I'm 100% sure that it uploads a lot of pictures that are not from the camera, e.g. screenshots and downloaded files.

I prefer the Camera Upload feature to do what it says, and not mix everything it finds on my phone in one folder. Is there any way to make it do what it says on the tin?

Answer (score 1):

Use [FolderSync Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite) and sync your default camera image folder on your Android. The folder path is: `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM`

Comment: I remember getting some perks (extra space, I think?) for using Camera Upload, at least in the beginning. Would that be affected somehow? Also, does FolderSync do "instant uploading" the way Camera Upload does?